# how to generate SAML metadata file

Tags: active-directory, saml, adfs

SAML metadata is used to share configuration information between the Identity Provider (IdP) and the Service Provider (SP). Metadata for the IdP and the SP is defined in XML files:

The IdP metadata XML file contains the IdP certificate, the entity ID, the redirect URL, and the logout URL, for example, saml_idp_metadata.xml.
The SP metadata XML file contains the SP certificate, the entity ID, the Assertion Consumer Service URL (ACS URL), and a log out URL (SingleLogoutService), for example, saml_sp_metadata.xml.
Before using SAML to log on to the Web Console, metadata from the IdP must be uploaded and metadata from the SP must be generated. After the SP metadata is generated, it must be shared with the IdP. Contact the IdP for instructions on securely sharing the SP metadata.

Answer (score 0):

- **Download Windows Identity Foundation SDK, below url**
  [image]

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4451

- **After install run fedutil.exe from sdk**
- **After open federation utility Create one empty web.config file with following content**

Now paste the web config path in “Application configuration location”.

- **Paste application url under section Application URL, click next**
  [image: FederationImage]
- **Select Use an Existing STS, click next**
- **Put metadata xml url , which is provided by client.**
  [image: Security Image]
- **Click next., select no encryption.**
  [image: NoEncryption]
- **Click next to add claims**
  [image: AddClaims]
- **Click next then you will get the summery.**
  [image: Summery]
- **Click finish., find location of web.config file, at that location one folder is created names as “FederationMetadata”**
- **Open this folder “FederationMetadata”, inside this one folder is exists, inside this folder one file is exists named as “FederationMetadata.xml”.
  This is your final xml file.**
- **Take a  sample userid, password from adfs/server team, to test your application.**
- **Then after open metadata xml and provide claims to adfs teams like**

  *Group
  Department
  Mail
  EmailAddesss
  Given Name
  Name
  Name ID
  Windows account name*
- **Once get confirmation from Adfs team (he will create trust on his server using our xml file). We can test our application using shared user credentials.**